# Hover effect for href links in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just got started with web design and I try to add a hover effect to this pretty old HTML, CSS Javascript code. What I want I actually pretty simple. If I hover over the image the images should get yellow.I also tried the css `a:hover` but that does not work either. Please give me a hint.

```html
<td class="mainMenu">
    <a href="n_home.html">
        <img onmouseover="yellow(this)" src="navig/home_up.gif" alt="Home" width="34" height="23" border="0" />
    </a>
</td>
```

```css
td.mainMenu {   
    width : 37px; 
    height: 26px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;    
}
```

```js
function yellow(x) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF00";
}
```

Comment: Is the image transparent? If not, how do you expect to see the background colour behind it?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you need to do is hide the image. So add the following code in the **yellow** function.

```
x.style.opacity = "0";
```

Add **id** to your **<td>**.

```
<td class="mainMenu" id="mainMenu">
```

Then you need to change the background color of **<td>** by adding the code in the same function

```
document.getElementById("mainMenu").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

Depending on the size of your td, the background color will be added.

Answer (score 1):

Your code working , the probleme is that the background changes in the back , this is why you dont see it

```js
function yellow(x) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF00";
}
```

```css
td.metanavigation { 
width : 37px; 
height: 26px;
text-align: left;
vertical-align: top; 
  }
```

```html
<td class="mainMenu">
<a href="n_home.html"><img onmouseover="yellow(this)" src="http://pngimg.com/upload/water_PNG3290.png" alt="Home" width="100" height="100" border="0" /></a>
</td>
```

Comment: what about x.style.color = "#FFFF00"?

Comment: @Marta the `color` style rule, effects text, not graphics.

Comment: @Marta 'style.color' changes text color ,  not backgrounds

Answer (score 1):

Piggy-backing off of Mohamed's response, you should define a CSS rule for the background color and simply add or remove it from the image.

The add and remove class functions are defined for usage on IE 9+ (http://YouMightNotNeedjQuery.com)

```js
function addClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList) el.classList.add(className);
  else el.className += ' ' + className;
}

function removeClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList) el.classList.remove(className);
  else el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
}
```

```css
td.metanavigation {
  width: 37px;
  height: 26px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<td class="mainMenu">
  <a href="n_home.html">
    <img src="http://pngimg.com/upload/water_PNG3290.png" alt="Home"
         onMouseover="addClass(this, 'yellow')"
         onMouseout="removeClass(this, 'yellow')"
         width="100" height="100"
         border="0" />
  </a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use a pesudo selectors.

All can be done in CSS no need for javascript.
Here is working fiddle `Here is the working` 
**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m_tanzi/jtgocvbt/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually it's incorrect to add a background color to the img element, and rather apply one to the surrounding/parent element.

```css
div.parent{
  background: red;
  }

div.parent:hover{
  background:yellow;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="parent">
      <img src="http://tny.im/4QH" />
 </div>
```

This can be achieved without any JS and only using CSS. The hover event is propagated to the parent div causing the background to change.

Hope this helps!